# SQL delete all rows for all children

Tags: mysql

Is it possible in MySQL to delete all children recursively based on a parent table?

Suppose I have

```
+-------+
|TBL1.id|  
+-------+  

+-------+--------------------------+  
|TBL2.id|TBL2.parentId (FK TBL1.id)|  
+-------+--------------------------+  

+-------+--------------------------+
|TBL3.id|TBL3.parentId (FK TBL2.id)|  
+-------+--------------------------+
```

Now, I can't delete all rows from TBL1 because TBL2 has references to TBL1.id, and I can't delete TBL2 because TLB3 has references to TBL2.

Is it possible to generate a SQL query using MySQL that will list the order the tables have to be deleted? Or that lists the dependency of tables, starting from the farthest child?

I don't want to drop tables, just delete all rows of a set of tables and their children, and their children, ...

Currently I have a several scripts, one per parent table to delete all children, but I'd like to automate that.

EDIT 1:
The database is in development mode, so new tables and constraints are still being added to it.

I don't own the database, which doesn't have cascade delete. I **could** add cascade delete to the copy that is sent to me, but that would be as much work as using the scripts I have today.

Comment: Have you attempted to modify the FK definitions to use `ON DELETE CASCADE`? Or do I misunderstand and that wouldn't meet your need?

Comment: [Documented here...](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html)

Comment: added more details to the post. Unfortunately cascade delete is not an option.

Comment: Do you want to **`delete`** rows or **`drop`** tables?

Comment: I want to delete rows.

Comment: `DELETE tbl1, tbl2, tble3 FROM tbl1 LEFT JOIN tbl2 ON tbl1.id = tbl2.parentid LEFT JOIN tbl3 ON tbl2.id = tbl3.parentid ;` This will drop all the rows form `tbl1` and all dependent rows in the other 2 tables.

Comment: This is what my script does. But it fails if a new TBL4 now depends on TBL1, TBL2, or TBL3.

Comment: @ypercube, any specific reason you are not converting that comment as answer.

Comment: @Rahul Not sure if the OP wants this or something more generic. Feel free to convert it to an answer though, if you like.

Comment: OP (me) wants a generic approach.

Comment: In that case, Ypercube answer is perfect; it's just that you may like to make it a dynamic query. OR consider having a stored proc where you can pass the table name as parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you want to delete all rows on TBL1 with id equal to 5, and all related rows in tables : TBL2 and TBL3, you can do it in a single transaction like this one :

```
START TRANSACTION
DELETE FROM TBL3 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TBL2 JOIN TBL1 ON TBL1.id = TBL2. parentId AND TBL1.id = 5 WHERE id = TBL3.parentId);
DELETE FROM TBL2 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TBL1 WHERE id = TBL2.parentId AND id = 5);
DELETE FROM TBL1 WHERE id = 5;
COMMIT
```

If you follow a convention naming fields on the tables, you can generate the script dynamically with PLSQL querying the [INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/tables-table.html) views :

```
SELECT table_name, column_name FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES t
   JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c ON c.table_name = t.table_name AND table_schema = 'db_name' 
  WHERE table_schema = 'db_name'
  AND table_name LIKE 'TBL_' AND column_name LIKE 'parentId'
  ORDER BY table_name DESC
```

Comment: This is what my script does. But it fails if a new TBL4 now depends on TBL1, TBL2, or TBL3. I am looking for a generic solution. Maybe reading the dictionary?

Comment: You can generate the script dynamically, but you have to follow a convention naming fields ...